# IMS Droid calee is Ringing but screen is black

Tags: sip, imsdroid

I am using Kamailio as a SIP server and IMS Droid (2.548.870 apk) as a client on Samsung Galaxy S4 mini. Both UEs Register fine and call invite and ringing works. But the callee doesn't have a UI to answer the call. Instead only a notification is shown and screen goes black.

[image: side by side calling and no answer]

Wireshark capture:

```
     20 29.739956553   15.20.70.54           192.168.12.246        GTP <SIP/SDP> 1511   Request: INVITE sip:404049876590093@Idea | 
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 55240, Dst Port: 5060
Session Initiation Protocol (INVITE)

 21 29.740452508   192.168.12.246        15.20.70.54           GTP <SIP> 389    Status: 100 Trying | 
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 5060, Dst Port: 55240
Session Initiation Protocol (100)

 22 29.742072855   192.168.12.246        15.20.70.84           GTP <IPv4> 1510   Fragmented IP protocol (proto=UDP 17, off=0, ID=0767) [Reassembled in #23]
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.12.246, Dst: 15.20.70.84
Data (1440 bytes)...

 23 29.742081602   192.168.12.246        15.20.70.84           GTP <SIP/SDP> 797    Request: INVITE sip:404049876590093@15.20.70.84:55973;transport=udp | 
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 5060, Dst Port: 55973
Session Initiation Protocol (INVITE)

 24 29.770937125   15.20.70.84           192.168.12.246        GTP <SIP> 1109   Status: 100 Trying (sent from the Transaction Layer) | 
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 55973, Dst Port: 5060
Session Initiation Protocol (100)

 25 29.771143131   15.20.70.84           192.168.12.246        GTP <SIP> 1270   Status: 180 Ringing | 
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 55973, Dst Port: 5060
Session Initiation Protocol (180)

 26 29.772058958   192.168.12.246        15.20.70.54           GTP <SIP> 839    Status: 180 Ringing | 
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 5060, Dst Port: 55240
Session Initiation Protocol (180)

 27 29.798929434   15.20.70.54           192.168.12.246        GTP <SIP> 1240   Request: PRACK sip:404049876590093@15.20.70.84:55973;transport=udp | 
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 55240, Dst Port: 5060
Session Initiation Protocol (PRACK)

 28 29.799730736   192.168.12.246        15.20.70.84           GTP <SIP> 1364   Request: PRACK sip:404049876590093@15.20.70.84:55973;transport=udp | 
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 5060, Dst Port: 55973
Session Initiation Protocol (PRACK)

 29 29.831885161   15.20.70.84           192.168.12.246        GTP <SIP> 788    Status: 200 OK | 
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 55973, Dst Port: 5060
Session Initiation Protocol (200)

 30 29.832420706   192.168.12.246        15.20.70.54           GTP <SIP> 439    Status: 200 OK | 
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 5060, Dst Port: 55240
Session Initiation Protocol (200)

 31 45.128850276   15.20.70.54           192.168.12.246        GTP <SIP> 554    Request: CANCEL sip:404049876590093@Idea | 
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 55240, Dst Port: 5060
Session Initiation Protocol (CANCEL)

 32 45.129697666   192.168.12.246        15.20.70.54           GTP <SIP> 434    Status: 200 canceling | 
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 5060, Dst Port: 55240
Session Initiation Protocol (200)

 33 45.131136260   192.168.12.246        15.20.70.84           GTP <SIP> 424    Request: CANCEL sip:404049876590093@15.20.70.84:55973;transport=udp | 
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 5060, Dst Port: 55973
Session Initiation Protocol (CANCEL)

 34 45.160845635   15.20.70.84           192.168.12.246        GTP <SIP> 433    Status: 200 OK | 
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 55973, Dst Port: 5060
Session Initiation Protocol (200)

 35 45.161061523   15.20.70.84           192.168.12.246        GTP <SIP> 1151   Status: 487 Request Cancelled | 
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 55973, Dst Port: 5060
Session Initiation Protocol (487)

 36 45.161344280   192.168.12.246        15.20.70.84           GTP <SIP> 433    Request: ACK sip:404049876590093@15.20.70.84:55973;transport=udp | 

User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 5060, Dst Port: 55973
Session Initiation Protocol (ACK)

 37 45.162048660   192.168.12.246        15.20.70.54           GTP <SIP> 720    Status: 487 Request Cancelled | 
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 5060, Dst Port: 55240
Session Initiation Protocol (487)

 38 45.188802828   15.20.70.54           192.168.12.246        GTP <SIP> 423    Request: ACK sip:404049876590093@Idea | 
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 55240, Dst Port: 5060
Session Initiation Protocol (ACK)
```

I was also trying to find IMS Droid active community. Is there any such?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug only for the specific device/android version.
Tried the same IMS Droid apk on another device (Xiaomi Redmi Note 3) and it was OK:

[image]

Adding the faulty device specifics for documentation:

Model Number GT-I9195I

Android Version 4.4.4

Kernel version 3.10.28-4321829 Apr 3 2015